# show one date from many date and Addition the amount

Tags: php, sql

I want to show another table. where show like this.

```
   Date                    Total Amount
2015-01-29                  10,000 BDT
2015-01-30                  45,000 BDT
2015-02-02                  10,000 BDT
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjMns.png
i am trying it on PHP . But i can do it properly. Please give me a solution. How i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try any like this ? :

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(amount) as `Total_Amount` 
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY `date`
```

According  code you provide just remember, coz you do SUM - you can't say what id row is, and coz of you use `as sum` there is no filed `amount` anymore but `sum`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, SUM(amount) as sum FROM deposit GROUP BY date"); 

 echo "<table border='1' > <tr> <th>Id</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Amount</th> </tr>";
 $i=0;
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i++;
    echo "<tr>"; echo "<td>". $i."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>". $row['date']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>". $row['sumt']."</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
 }
 echo "</table>";
```